# how to test a method of swapping 2 elements in array using Junit

Tags: java, arrays, testing, junit

I have write 2 method in class which swaps 2 elements in array. But I am not sure how to test my methods in JUnit, I want to test if the 2 elements as correctly swapped, and to check if the index in array is valid. Finally a test to check if method will swap strings as well as double.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GenericExample {

int index1;
int index2; 

public static <T> T [] swap(T[] array, int index1, int index2)
{
    T temp = array[index1];
    array [index1] = array [index2] ;
    array [index2] = temp;

    return array;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer [ ] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    System.out.println("Array is: " + Arrays.toString(array));
    swap(array,1,3);
    System.out.println("Array is: " + Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

}

This is the test class which I have created to test the code of this.
[TestClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pva16.png)

Comment: There is no jUnit-related code in your question. You need to create a test case and perform asserts.

Comment: What do you mean by "how"?

Comment: Hint: spent some more time formatting your input next time. And: a lot of bad practices in your code; like *shadowing* the class fields index1, index2 by using the same names as method parameters. It is also not really helpful to work on the **input** array; and to then return it. You should either create a copy and return that; or work on the input array and make the method void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
@Test
public testSwappingFirstAndSecondElement() {
  String input[] = { "1", "2"};
  String expectedOutput[] = { "2", "1"};

  assserThat(swap(input, 0, 1), is(expectedOutput));
}
```

is about all you need. Meaning: you create some "known" input; you create "known output" for a specific swap operation; and then you invoke your swap method and check if the returned array matches your expectation.

The *real* work here: determining all the testcases you have to write, corner conditions and such. For example you would also have tests that call swap(null, -1, -2) ... just to be sure that all such invalid inputs result in that result that you define should come out ...

Comment: I have tried this but asserThat gives me an error and how are they linked?

Comment: and I did add a method for it but still no luck

Comment: I understand what the code is supposed to do but even if the output is different to the the expected output it does not do anything it is just considered to be correct

Comment: Please have a look at the test class  which i have created based on you code.